# Flutter: http request List<Dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<int>

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send http request with the array List that has String values.

```
var gameCode = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

I am trying to send `gameCode` value with the below.

```
getListOfGames() async {
    try {
      print(gameCode);
  
        'http://localhost:8232',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            'game_code': gameCode,
          },
        ),
      );
}
```

However, I get this `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'` error. When I send just empty `[]`, then it works. So, I think it is about the type. I need to convert `List<String>` to `List<dynamic>` or something like that.

How can I change the `gameCode` list to `List<dynamic>` so can I include this to my `http.post` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<dynamic> gameCode = ['1', '2', '3'];

// ...

body: jsonEncode({
  'game_code': gameCode,
},),
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @Riwen am not a writer. My answer is quite simple